Visual Studio version 17.10.2: how to create pull request in devops and not in VS?
I just upgraded VS to the latest version.
If I want to merge a branch to another one I right click on it and then select create pull request, but then it does that in VS and I need it to be in DevOps.
If I do a push I get a choice to create a pull request in VS or in browser.
How can I set it so that it will always use browser?
